# How to implement a Set Data Structure in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, set

I have always wondered how would you implement a Set in Java. Can we implement it just like we implement a HashMap using a LinkedList and an object(Cell) which holds a Key and Value? How would you handle the uniqueness part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set internally implements a map.So each value in a set is just a key in map.So its uniqueness in maintained.

[Here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-sets-are-implemented-internally-in.html) is the link.So that you get clear idea how set works internally.
Also few stack Answers.
[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781868/internal-implementation-of-java-util-hashmap-and-hashset) , [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453476/hash-how-does-it-work-internally)

Answer (score 5):

Basically, a Set is just a Map that only holds keys. So you should inform yourself about mappingalgorithms. Note: the HashSet for example is actually just an adapter for the HashMap. the add-method of HashSet simply uses HashMap.put(value , SomeDummyValue).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a code snippet to explain above answers

```
public HashSet() { map = new HashMap<>(); }
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}

// Since PRESENT is a constant, for all keys we have same value in backup HashMap called map.

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Map

**Basics first**

What are the features of Set datastructures?

1. Each element get stored only once.
2. Query for an item in Set should be fastest, i.e. in `O(1)`.
3. If an item to be inserted is already present in Set, then don't insert. If it's not present then insert.

If we look closely, which datastructure can implement it?
Answer is `Map`, because we just keep a record of which value present. And we can query in `O(1)` time.

Answer (score -2):

```
class HashSetBasicImpl<K> {

        static class Entry<K> {
            private K key;
            private Entry<K> next;

            Entry(K key) {
                key = key;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        private Entry<K>[] entries;

        public HashSetBasicImpl() {
            // fixed size
            map =new Entry[100];
        }

        public boolean contains(K key) {
            int idx = key.hashCode();
            Entry<K> start = entries[idx];
            while(start != null) {
                if(start.key == key) {
                    return true;
                }
                start = start.next;
            }
            return  false;

        }

        public boolean add(K key) {

            Entry<K> entry = new Entry(key);
            int idx = key.hashCode();

            // check if entry exists
           if(contains(key)) {
               return false;
           }
            // add as first entry
            start = entries[idx];
            if(start == null) {
                entries[idx]= new Entry(key);
                return true;
            }
            // add as nth entry
            Entry prev = null;
            while(start != null) {
                prev = start;
                start = start.next;
            }
            prev.next = new Entry(key);
            return true;
        }
}
```