# Adding elements into HashSet

Tags: java

I have a question about how add method in the HashSet works. I am relatively new to Java so please don't mind if this too naive.
I was looking into the source code for HashSet and found that the 'add' method in the HashSet is saving the values in a HashMap.

```
public boolean More ...add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

What I figured out is that the 'e' is the key and the add method adds the new element as a key and not as a value and thus the HashSet will have no duplicates.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right.  I know the excitement of looking at Java source code is uncontrollable at times but seriously, what's the question now?

Comment: You know it already... If you want to dig deep... Follow the link... http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-sets-are-implemented-internally-in.html

Comment: That's basically correct. It just uses the same value `PRESENT` for all the entries. Nobody cared to create a separate hash set implementation, instead the existing `HashMap` code was reused (even though it takes more memory to store those references to the `PRESENT` object).

Comment: Good job for actually going into core java code yourself to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks,I wanted to know that if    PRESENT is used as a dummy value which the Set does not care about?

Comment: @DhrubojyotiBhattacharjee Yes, that's essentially what happens - `PRESENT` is used as a dummy value.

Comment: Yes, the value of `PRESENT` is not important, only that it's not null.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.  The answers to this SO question go into more detail:

[Internal implementation of java.util.HashMap and HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781868/internal-implementation-of-java-util-hashmap-and-hashset)